# Why doesn't my drop down menu work?

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to change the visibility from hidden to visible so just check my jquery and tell me what is wrong. If more is needed, please let me know.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#navLink1").hover(function(){
        $("#dropDown1").css("visibility", "visible");
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you give us more code, and perhaps a JSFiddle? I'm assuming `#dropDown1` is set to `visibility:hidden` and not `display:none`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
$("#navLink1").hover(function(){
    $("#dropDown1").toggle();
});
```

It toggles the `display` property so instead of using `visibility: hidden;` use `display: none;` in your CSS.

Alternatively you could use:

```
$("#navLink1").hover(function(){
    $("#dropDown1").css("visibility", "visible");
}, function(){
    $("#dropDown1").css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/gTuxP/

Comment: still no solved problem. I might have to use an if statement and completly exclude the css hidden thing.

Comment: I don't mean an option drop down I mean like a navigation drop down menu.

Comment: yes Thats not the kind of drop down i want. You know how when you go on a website and the navigation has sub menus. That's what I'm trying to make.

Comment: Thats a new level of stupid I forgot to add .js at the end when I added my script to the html. Thanks for the help though. I'll mark your answer as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.show()`, you can't override `display:none` (*if you are using it to hide the element*) with `visibility:visible`

```
$("#dropDown1").show();
```

Comment: But the element is already hidden with css using visibility: hidden

Comment: @user2489995 In that case, you have nothing wrong in your code, Have you included jQuery ? see console for any error ?

Comment: I will check a few things just wait and if it works I will check your post as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

use `slideToggle()` for a sliding effect.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#navLink1").hover(function(){
        $("#dropDown1").slideToggle();
    });
});
```